# Setting up SOAP webservice using Zend Framework in PHP

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, soap, routes, client

I'm trying to set up a Web Service using a standard Zend Framework project.

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/webservice/index' : Extra content at the end 
of the document in 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client\Common.php:51 
Stack trace: #0 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client\Common.php(51): 
SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...', Array) #1 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php(1026): 
Zend_Soap_Client_Common->__construct(Array, 'http://localhos...', Array) #2 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php(1182): 
Zend_Soap_Client->_initSoapClientObject() #3 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php(1106): 
Zend_Soap_Client->getSoapClient() #4 [internal function]: 
Zend_Soap_Client->__call('getCompanies', Array) #5 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\application\controllers
\WebserviceController.php(98): 
Zend_Soap_Client->getCompanies() #6 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\application\controllers\WebserviceC in 
C:\wamp\www\delegate-events-portal\library\Zend\Soap\Client\Common.php on line 51
```

**Code**

application/controllers/WebserviceController.php

```
class WebserviceController extends Portal_BaseController
{
    public $resourceId = 'Webservice';
    private $client;

    public function init(){}

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        //Set up the Web Service Manager
        $auto = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
        $auto->setClass('Webservice_Manager');
        $auto->handle();
    }

    public function clientAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        try
        {
            $this->client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://localhost/webservice/index');
        }
        catch(SoapFault $s)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($s);
            echo '<pre>';
            die('ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        print_r($this->client->getCompanies());
    }
}
```

library/Webservice/Manager.php

```
class Webservice_Manager
{

    /**
     * Returns all the companies for a particular summit
     * @param int $summitID
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCompanies($summitID = 118)
    {
        $companiesModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_Company();
        return $companiesModel->getCompaniesAndAttendees($summitID, NULL, NULL, true, NULL)->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the attendees for a particular summit
     * @param int $summitID
     * @param int $companyID
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttendees($summitID = 118, $companyID = 3767) 
    {
        $attendeesModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_Attendee();
        return $attendeesModel->getAttendees($summitID, $companyID, false)->toArray();
    }
}
```

**Potential Solution**

I'm pretty sure the issue is caused by the routing system in Zend. When I take the server code and place it outside of the framework (in the root folder), the code works fine. The only changes I made to the code in this scenario was the location of the wsdl. I used an absolute path and required any of the files I needed.

With this in mind, how do I get the web service to work from within my Zend Project and not when it's outside?

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: Why are you extending `Portal_BaseController`? Does it extend `Zend_Controller_Action`?

Also, is this app meant to be a server or a client? The reason I ask is because I assumed you were writing a server app, but I don't see any code to instantiate a `Zend_Soap_Server` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `indexAction` to use `Zend_Soap_Server`. It's not AutoDiscover but gets the job done.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    //Set up the Web Service Manager
    $auto = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/webservice/index'
    ));
    $auto->setClass('Webservice_Manager');
    $auto->handle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function webserviceAction(){
     $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`enter code here`       
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    //Set up the Web Service
        $auto = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/webservice/webservice'
    ));
        $auto->setClass('Webservice_Manager');
        $auto->handle();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.